# When using COM interop, why does late binding fix the "ByRef value type parameter cannot be null" error?

Tags: c++, vb.net, com, com-interop

I'm using an interop dll in a VB.NET project to get access to some functions in a MFC project.

```
Dim bIsSupposedToWork As Boolean = True
Dim api As API = GetObject(, "MyProject.API")

api.Function1()  ' << Function1 returns void, and this works OK

' Function2 returns a long:
If Not bIsSupposedToWork Then
   ' This next line crashes the application with the message "ByRef value type parameter cannot be null"- error
   api.Function2()
Else
   ' But this works fine:
   Dim o As Object = api
   o.Function2()
End If
```

Why?

Comment: Turns out that in the MFC class the return value parameter for DISP_FUNCTION was defined as VT_EMPTY. Changing it to VT_I4 lets me use "function2" without first assigning the api object to the object variable.

Still not sure why it runs perfectly when using late binding, but I'm guessing that I was avoiding some runtime type-checking in the "interop layers in between" when doing that?

Answer (score 2):

You are fooling the compiler, preventing it from checking that you wrote the correct code.  An Object.Foo() call is late bound, it is sorted out at runtime which exact function should be called.  The compiler can't do any checking, it doesn't know what methods the object supports.  The underlying plumbing is COM's IDispatch interface.

Needless to say perhaps, this doesn't solve anything, it just makes a loud bang at runtime.

Not sure why you are doing this, maybe the .idl in the MFC project is missing the [out,retval] attribute for the function return value.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I should have been clearer in my question: this is a runtime error.
First example crashes the application with the given error. Second example runs smoothly.
But your comment made me re-check the idl and when found to be OK, the BEGIN_DISPATCH_MAP and the DISP_FUNCTION for the function, where the problem turned out to be. (See comment to my original question)